# how to extract dataframe header values and stored in a qlistwidget using pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qcheckbox

I have a GUI app that load csv file as dataframe in a QtableView and perform some functions on the data  one of the function is to extract the headers  and store it in a  QlistWidget with check box  or a group of checkbox.Until now i am able to just print the header values.

## code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import pandas as pd

from PandasModel import PandasModel

import seaborn as sns
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline.offline import iplot
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
       
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
       
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.pathLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pathLE, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        

        
        self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select File", self)
        self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.loadBtn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 4)

       
        self.displayHeader = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Display header", self)
        self.displayHeader.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_header(self.df))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.displayHeader, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)

        self.pandasTv.setSortingEnabled(True)


     def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.pandasTv.setModel(model)
        self.df = df


    def print_df_header(self,df):
        print(self.df.columns.tolist())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.newCheckBox=QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)

        
        
        header=QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        
        self.listWidget.addItem(header)
        self.listWidget.addItem("Data")
        
        header.setCheckState(1)
        header.setText("Header")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question it was very easy  and i added a checkbox for each item.

```
 def print_df_header(self,df):
        savelist = list(self.df)
        for item in savelist:
            qitem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem ( ) 
            qitem.setText ( item ) 
            qitem.setCheckState ( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked ) 
            self.header_list.addItem ( qitem )
        print(list(self.df))
```